# AccessQueue QR Action failed Error

Tags: soap, sabre, sabredav

When I request a QR action (after QueueAccessLLSRQ):

```
<QueueAccessRQ Version="2.0.7"  xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"><Navigation Action="QR" ></Navigation><QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="XXXX" Number="101" ></QueueIdentifier></QueueAccessRQ>
```

The response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>XXXX</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>convId</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service>QueueAccessLLSRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>QueueAccessLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>XXXX</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2017-02-14T10:18:04</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">XXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><QueueAccessRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.7">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-02-14T04:18:04-06:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>QH NOT AVAILABLE FOR THIS PNR</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</QueueAccessRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

Someone know whats happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing on that request is to remove the PNR that you currently have in your working area, from just a single queue. In this case you are attempting to remove the PNR from the queue 101 in PCC XXXX.

The reason for getting that error is that you did not have a PNR your working area.

Once you have that you may attempt this again and should get one of two responses
Failure: PNR NOT ON REQUESTED QUEUE
Success: QUEUE REMOVAL IN PROGRESS

Comment: Hello @Wisdoom, Could you please explain a bit more about "you did not have a PNR your working area". I retrieve the details of a PNR and then try to remove it from queue. But it returns *QH NOT AVAILABLE FOR THIS PNR*.

Comment: According to format finder, you need to have pulled the PNR from a queue. Opening the PNR is not enough for doing QR, because it cannot determine from which queue to remove the PNR. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Wisdoom for your explanations!